# NuGet Restore package in visual studio 2015 using .Net Core is not automatic

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

When I open a web application project using .Net Core in visual studio 2015 community the package restore is not automatic and I have to use dotnet restore in cmdprompt and restart the visual studio 2015 to complete the package restore.
 I already checked the nuget settings (yes, the automatic restore in checkbox is check and also the enable package restore)

I found out that the  package restore works well in .net framework in visual studio 2015 and not in .net core

Please help how to make it automatic when I used .net core in visual studio 2015 (not using cmd.)

Thanks:)

Comment: Right clicking on the project (not solution) and selecting Restore Packages should work too. And I don't think you need to restart VS after `dotnet restore`.

Comment: I already did that. I right click on the project,select restore packages and it's not working. I dont know why. Then i tried to close the VS and reopen it again after that the references show up.